# "No instance for (MonadLevelDB IO)" compilation error in test suite

Tags: haskell, leveldb

I am trying to use [higher-leveldb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/higher-leveldb-0.5.0.2/) in my Haskell application, and I am getting a compilation error in my test suite that I do not understand (or at least, I do not have the knowledge to properly fix it).

For context, I have the following helper to fetch and decode a user from the database:

```hs
getUser :: (MonadLevelDB m) => Text -> m (Maybe User)
getUser uuid = do
  let key = toStrict . encode $ uuid
  result <- LevelDB.get key -- m (Maybe Value)
  case result of
      Just value -> return ( decodeStrict' value :: Maybe User) -- Ideal type
      Nothing    -> return Nothing
```

And the following test suite:

```hs
type EuphrateMonad m = (MonadLevelDB m, MonadUnliftIO m, MonadIO m)

main :: IO ()
main = runCreateLevelDB "/tmp/mydb" "test" levelDBMain

levelDBMain :: (EuphrateMonad m) => m ()
levelDBMain = do
    setup
    test <- liftIO $ testSpec "euphrate" spec
    liftIO $ Test.Tasty.defaultMain test


spec :: Spec
spec = parallel $ do
    it "Fetch an already-existing user" $ do
        user <- getUser "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c"
        user `shouldBe` ( Just $ User "toto" "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c" True "toto92" "" )

    it "Delete a user" $ do
      deleteUser "2e940724-936e-4700-826b-367faabac141"
      user <- getUser "2e940724-936e-4700-826b-367faabac141"
      user `shouldBe` Nothing

users :: [User]
users = [ User "toto" "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c" True "toto92" ""
        , User "Jérôme" "2e940724-936e-4700-826b-367faabac141" False "jéjédu32" "nah."
        ]

setup :: (EuphrateMonad m) => m ()
setup =
  for_ users createUser
```

Now, the error I get is :

```
euphrate/test/Main.hs:29:17: error:
    • No instance for (MonadLevelDB IO) arising from a use of ‘getUser’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        user <- getUser "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c"
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do user <- getUser "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c"
            user
              `shouldBe`
                (Just
                   $ User
                       "toto" "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c" True "toto92" "")’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        _ <- it "Fetch an already-existing user"
               $ do user <- getUser "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c"
                    user
                      `shouldBe`
                        (Just
                           $ User
                               "toto" "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c" True "toto92" "")
   |
29 |         user <- getUser "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c"
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am first and foremost looking for ways to better understand this type of situations. I have some basic understanding of transformers, through Reader and Writer, but I don't feel very helped by what I know of that.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with higher-levelDB but from the look of the code, I think the issue is probably that when you write lines like these:

```hs
spec :: Spec
spec = parallel $ do
    it "Fetch an already-existing user" $ do
        user <- getUser "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c"
        user `shouldBe` ( Just $ User "toto" "664798e1-7fac-4e0b-9fc6-757f4fb0409c" True "toto92" "" )
```

You're not in the monadic context you need. Using `it` you only live in the hspec context, which is ignorant of all DB-related things. Have a look at the (fairly abstract) signature of `it`:

```hs
it :: (HasCallStack, Example a) => String -> a -> SpecWith (Arg a)
```

We're far from the constraint of your `EuphrateMonad` stack there. So you'll need to add something in between, to enter the required context (getting the connection to levelDB, managing transaction, etc.).

In such cases, I find it helps to look at the library code directly and see if there are any test suites and how the author create their context. You're in luck, [there are tests in this library](https://github.com/jeremyjh/higher-leveldb/blob/master/test/Database/LevelDB/HigherSpec.hs). Look at the definition and use of `withDBT` and `withDBRT`, this should point you towards the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have looked for tests in the first place indeed :)